Can oscillations occur in moment sequence of a random variable?
If $X$ is a nonnnegative, nondegenerate random variable, the Lp norm $m(p) = E[X^p]^{1/p}$ is a strictly increasing function of $p\geq 1$. I am curious about whether it is ever possible that $\lim_{p\to\infty} \frac{m(p)}{p}$ can fail to exist. In other words, a situation where it does not equal infinity or any finite value, but rather the lim sup and lim inf fail to agree. Such a situation would imply there are oscillations in $m(p)$ but I can't think of any random variables that would produce such a moment sequence.

by non degenerate, you mean with a continuous pdf to exclude counterexamples like a Bernoulli variable ?

Sorry no I mean that X is not a constant with probability one. If X is a constant then m(p) is not strictly increasing. (it just equals one for all p).

Thinking about this some more, I believe it is possible. A similar problem relating to tail probabilities was discussed in another question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2126173/23331
